# Docusign tab auto-population (\\*) populating wrong tabs

Tags: docusignapi

When using the auto-populate feature I noticed that it was auto-populating tabs that I thought it should not have been.

E.g. I have two tabs *PhoneNumber* and *AdditionalPhoneNumber*. I want to populate all occurrences of the *PhoneNumber* tab in the envelope. I set the value for *PhoneNumber* in the request using the tab label \\*PhoneNumber but I see that *AdditionalPhoneNumber* is also getting populated. I think that it should not have been since they are two different tab labels.

(Docusign documentation: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/  under the *Automatically Populating Tabs* section)

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

if I'm not mistaken the problem is that you are using a wildcard (\*PhoneNumber) which means you want to match any field that ends with "PhoneNumber".  If you remove the \* you should get only fields named exactly PhoneNumber.

Comment: This didn't work. According to the documentation (linked in the post above) \\\\* is required for auto population to work at all